# React Native - Sqlite Encryption

Tags: database, react-native, sqlite, encryption

I am developing a mobile application with React Native. Are these tables accessible when we create a local database? Can a normal user go to the directory and view the database? They can log into the application with a password. If the data can be viewed from the table, it is meaningless. I store the passwords by encrypting them with bcrypt but other data is normal. I am using sqlite database, react-native-sqlite-storage package. Can i encrypt the database? I did not see anything about encryption in documents.

Comment: I don't know about react-native-sqlite-storage, but I do know that you can do it with realm for example: https://realm.io/docs/javascript/latest/#encryption.